# Extract data after matching pattern in ruby

Tags: ruby

`puts myvalue[1]` (my value is a String)

```
#My COmments
#Checked on 54
[Roll]
new line = see, that, cfiu\poli
check_that = roll\uiju, rolldeny that, its=oik, mao\ikir4
stares = roll\okik, roll\asde4, roll\kz98e
```

I'm trying to extract after Roll and assign in to an array

```
groups = myvalue[1].match(/^[Roll].*/)
```

Output I got

```
new line = see that cfiu\poli
```

instead of (expected one)

```
new line = see that cfiu\poli
check_that = roll\uiju, rolldeny that, its=oik, mao\ikir4
stares = roll\okik, roll\asde4, roll\kz98e
```

How to do it, thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the output you get. Could you give a complete example? I assume you want to match "all lines not starting with '[Roll]'", is that right? That would be `^(?!\[Roll\]).*/mg`. Your current regex matches the first line starting with either 'R', 'o' or 'l'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> string = "String begins here
[Roll]
new line = this is new line content
check_that = check that line content
stares = stares content"

> required_string = string.split("[Roll]").last.strip
# new line = this is new line content
# check_that = check that line content
# stares = stares content
```

### Update:

```
> first_arry = required_string.split("\n").map{|e| e.split("=")}.map(&:first)
#=> ["new line ", "check_that ", "stares "] 
> second_arry = required_string.split("\n").map{|e| e.split("=")}.map(&:last)
#=> [" this is new line content", " check that line content", " stares content"]
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.
I'm sorry its an addition to my asked question.Any idea how to split based on the delimiter = and get the values as an array below

`first_arr = ["new line", "check_that", "stares "]`

`second_arr = [its corresponding splitted values]`

Comment: @voltas `first_arr = split("=")[0]; second+arr = split("=")[1];`

Comment: @RamonMarques :  thanks for the suggestion but, I'm getting only the first value i.e `new line` instead of `["new line", "check_that", "stares "]`

On printing second_array, i get as ` this is new line content

check_that`

Comment: @voltas actually make another question

Comment: It seems you are trying to parse an INI-file. You could use a library for that: https://github.com/twp/inifile

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke : Its an unorganized input file, but will give a try using ini parser. Thanks for your time. +1 for the inifile option

Comment: @voltas : glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Change your groups assign line to this:

```
groups = myvalue[1].partition(/\[Roll\]/).last
```

Comment: Thanks for the partition method